# Stabilization of operation on a collection of families

Tags: general-topology, set-theory

I have recently considered the problem the following problem, and was not sure how to search for an answer:

Given a collection of sets  $ \mathcal{F}=\{  F_\alpha \} \subseteq \mathcal{P}(X) $ we can denote the topology generated by those sets $\tau(\mathcal{F})$, and also the sigma algebra generated by $\mathcal{F}$ by $\sigma(\mathcal{F})$. We know that the Borel sigma-algebra is:

$$ \mathcal{B}_{X}=\sigma \Big( \tau(\mathcal{S}) \Big) \quad \text{where } \; \mathcal{S} \; \text{generates the topology of} \; X $$

And we can define generally $\eta(\mathcal{F}):= \sigma\Big( \tau(\mathcal{F}) \Big)$. It is obvious that $\eta(F)\subseteq \mathcal{P}(X)$ and that $\eta\Big( \mathcal{P}(X) \Big)=\mathcal{P}(X)$. I was wondering there are some conditions under which this operation stabilizes. i.e, does there exists $n$ such that $\eta^n(\mathcal{F})=\eta^{n+1}(\mathcal{F})$. For example does $\eta(\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}})$ eventually stablize?

If this is a well known subject, I would welcome any references educating on the subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\eta(\mathcal{B}_{\Bbb R}) = \mathscr{P}(X)$. All singletons are Borel, and the topology generated by singletons is discrete, and then we stop at the full power set. The same thus holds in any $T_1$ space. So in order to get a non-stabilising example we need a very non-$T_1$ space with enough open sets, somehow.

Comment: So you're saying that under my notation, if $X$ is a $T_1$ space, already $\tau(\mathcal{B}_X)=\mathcal{P}(X)$?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur yes of course, that’s obvious

Comment: @Keen-ameteur $T_1$ means singletons are closed and thus the topology generated by them contains all unions of singletons.